# Symfony Update Form Collection From Inside Controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

[image: Image of the form collection]

I have been looking for 4 days now and can't find anything on the web about this. I have a form collection of votes. Right above this is a picture of what it looks like. When the user clicks the Vote button I need to update the Count field that is right above it. How do I do this inside the Controller? When I press the Vote button, the whole entire form gets submitted and I don't know which Count Property to increment. Is there a better way to be doing this? I want to keep this as a form collection, that way I can add  some custom validation constraints to the form. Please help! I will add some of my code below this just for clarification.

ps. If you guys have feedback on a better way to do this, please let me know.

Votes Entity:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: joshuacrawmer
 * Date: 11/19/15
 * Time: 11:19 AM
 */

namespace Vote\FoodBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Votes
{

    protected $votes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->votes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getVotes()
    {
        return $this->votes;
    }
}
```

Vote Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Vote\FoodBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Vote
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Vote
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="count", type="integer")
     */
    private $count;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MonthlySnack", inversedBy="vote")
     */
    private $monthlySnack;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set count
     *
     * @param integer $count
     *
     * @return Vote
     */
    public function setCount($count)
    {
        $this->count = $count;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get count
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCount()
    {
        return $this->count;
    }

    /**
     * Set monthlySnack
     *
     * @param \Vote\FoodBundle\Entity\MonthlySnack $monthlySnack
     *
     * @return Vote
     */
    public function setMonthlySnack(\Vote\FoodBundle\Entity\MonthlySnack $monthlySnack = null)
    {
        $this->monthlySnack = $monthlySnack;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get monthlySnack
     *
     * @return \Vote\FoodBundle\Entity\MonthlySnacks
     */
    public function getMonthlySnack()
    {
        return $this->monthlySnack;
    }
}
```

Votes Type:

```
<?php

namespace Vote\FoodBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class VotesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('votes', 'collection', array('type' => new VoteType()));

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'Vote\FoodBundle\Entity\Votes',
            )
        );

    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'vote_foodbundle_votes';
    }
}
```

Vote Type:

```
<?php

namespace Vote\FoodBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class VoteType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

            ->add('count', 'text')
            ->add('monthlySnack')
            ->add('vote', 'submit');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'Vote\FoodBundle\Entity\Vote',
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'vote_foodbundle_vote';
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if I did understand it right, "Vote" buttuon should be bound to an onclick event javascript, instead submit. Because submit here not manke any sense. So onclick handler should increment the vote count by one.

Comment: Thank you for your help, But I need a solution that does not require javascript, as I want to build this out with just Symfony and PHP.

Comment: okay, just remember that not always it's possible. ;)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I know it's possible cause I had an interview with a company a month ago, and they needed me to do this for the interview. I could not figure it out! Sigh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change if any of this buttons clicked http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-submitting-multiple-buttons.

Just make something like:

```
<?php
//....
    foreach ($form->get('votes') as $voteForm) {
        if ($voteForm->get('vote')->isClicked()) {
            $vote = $voteForm->getData(); //Here is clicked vote object and u can...
            $vote->increment(); // ... for example increment counter (better than setCount(getCount()+1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: One more question for you Ziumin. If a user votes for a specific monthly snack, then I save the monthly snack in a cookie. I'm trying to add a custom validation constraint to the Vote Class that will get the cookie from the requestStack object and if the monthly snack has already been voted for, It throws an error. Setting up the custom constraint class is easy, but how do I go about getting the voted for object inside the custom validator class? Each vote object gets passed into the validator and I'm not sure how to find out which one was clicked on fromm inside the validator class.

Comment: Or Maybe you have a recommendation of a better way to do this, just let me know. Thanks Ziumin.

Comment: It seems like business requirement, not the form validation one. So I see two ways. The first is to prevent the choice of voted snack. And the second is to check this rule out of form validation (you can still `addError` to your form if needed).

Comment: if I check it out of form validation, should I just create a utility class and add the validation there?

Comment: Yes, it will be nice solution. But as for me it's more Specification then Validation

Comment: Okay. Thanks. this helps.